# ServiceBehavior with custom constructor. Need to inject dependencies

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection

I have a custom `ServiceBehavior` implemented this way, as an attribute that decorates the WCF Service:

```
public sealed class NHibernateSessionServiceBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public Type ServiceType { get; set; }
    public IConfigurator Configurator { get; set; }

    public NHibernateSessionServiceBehavior(Type serviceType, IConfigurator configurator)
    {
        ServiceType = serviceType;
        Configurator = configurator;
    }

    #region Implementation of IServiceBehavior

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        NHibernateSessionHelper.Instance.InitializeSessionFactory(Configurator);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatch in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatch in channelDispatch.Endpoints)
            {
                endpointDispatch.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new NHibernateMessageInspector(ServiceType));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The problem I have is that I need to pass to the attribute constructor an instance of `IConfigurator`, but the compiler obviously don't let me do that. I need a way to add this behavior to the Service injecting the `IConfigurator` instance. 
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason that injecting via the property or using a service locator inside the constructor is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this post: [Using Instance Provider and ServiceHostFactory to Construct the Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323725%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This series also can be helpful:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fabio/archive/2009/03/24/inversion-of-control-with-wcf-and-unity.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/fabio/archive/2009/03/24/inversion-of-control-with-wcf-and-unity-part-ii.aspx

Comment: I finally ended using an InstanceProvider to create my service instances with a parameter constructor. ServiceHostFactory was not necessary, because I'm self hosting my service. Thanks for the info!